# C# find child class via parent class

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have 3 classes `PropiedadEspecificaFilm`, `PropiedadEspecificaBook` and `PropiedadEspecificaMusic` which inherit from `Product`.

```
public partial class PropiedadEspecificaBook : Product
{
    public string ISBN { get; set; }
    public string author { get; set; }
    public long productId { get; set; }
      //Equals
      //ToString
}

public partial class PropiedadEspecificaMusic : Product
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string artist{ get; set; }
    public long productId { get; set; }
      //Equals
      //ToString
}

public partial class PropiedadEspecificaMusic : Product
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string artist{ get; set; }
    public long productId { get; set; }
      //Equals
      //ToString
}

public partial class Product
{
    public Product()
    {
        this.OrderLines = new HashSet<OrderLine>();
        this.Comments = new HashSet<Comment>();
    }

    public long id { get; set; }
    public string productName { get; set; }
    public decimal price { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime releaseDate { get; set; }
    public short stock { get; set; }
    public long categoryId { get; set; }
  }
```

Is there a way to know which one of the `PropiedadEspecifica` has the `productId` I am looking for?

Comment: I think you are better off modifying `Product` to hold the _ProductId_. And, if in the middle of processing you need to know the specific Sub-Class, you can use `this.GetType()`

Comment: Though one should try and structure the processing so it is generic, and leverages polymorphism rather than having an inheritance but then doing an @if type equals this do this else if type equals that do that" - not much point C# supporting polymorphism if that's how we're gonna code!

Comment: As an aside, I'd strongly encourage you to start following .NET naming conventions as soon as you can.

Comment: Indeed, if you're naming things thus for some reason like JSON serialization you should know a) most serializers should default to providing lowercase json attribs for PascalCase C# public properties and b) if they don't then they will have a way of specifying what attr Name to use for a property (such as newtonsoft's `[JsonProperty("jsonNameHere")]public string CSharpNameHere`

Comment: I am trying to compare with product.GetType() == (PropiedadEspecificaBook)), but it gives me an error "propiedadEspecificaBook is not valid in the given context".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding a virtual Dictionary<String, String> FindPropiedadEspecificaMethod() in Product. And then Overriding in each PropiedadEspecifica. Sorry because the problem was bad explained.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if all products share a property you should declare that in the parent class and not in the children. The children should only have the properties that differ from the parent class.

I also strongly suspect you do not need to mark your classes as partial (that is used if you want to split your class definition up, it is not intended for inheritance).

I also changed so the public properties are capitalized since that is the general convention for c# naming.

```
public class PropiedadEspecificaBook : Product
{
  public string ISBN { get; set; }
  public string Author { get; set; }
}

public class PropiedadEspecificaMusic : Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Artist{ get; set; }
}

public class PropiedadEspecificaMusic : Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Artist{ get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public Product()
    {
        this.OrderLines = new HashSet<OrderLine>();
        this.Comments = new HashSet<Comment>();
    }

    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public short Stock { get; set; }
    public long CategoryId { get; set; }
    public long ProductId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please also recommend c# established naming conventions for public members